# SonarQube Unit Tests from Jenkins not showing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jenkins, sonarqube, intern

I am running SonarQube 4.2 and am initiating a multiproject (mostly JavaScript) analysis from Jenkins.  I am not getting any data on my unit tests though - these are generated with Intern/Istanbul and output to a Junit format.  There are no errors in the logs.  I know the report format is good because it displays fine in Jenkins

My configuration is:

```
sonar.projectKey=${JOB_ID}:${JOB_ID}
sonar.projectName=${JOB_ID}
sonar.projectVersion=${BUILD_NUMBER}

sonar.verbose=true

sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
sonar.junit.reportsPath=reports/unit
sonar.js.coveragePlugin=cobertura
sonar.cobertura.reportsPath=reports/coverage

sonar.sources=src
sonar.tests=tests
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some properties, this are the property sonar uses to find the tests, the results and the jacoco plugin.

```
sonar.tests=test
sonar.junit.reportsPath=build/test-results
sonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco
sonar.jacoco.reportPath=build/jacoco/test.exec
```

where test-results is where the results of your tests go, you need to execute your tests with gradle or ant or maven first.

Comment: Even adding this property does not show the unit test widget in the dashboard.

Comment: Look at this answer this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446045/sonar-does-not-shows-up-code-coverage-after-build-successful-with-jenkins-sonar

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it is a different use case - I am using JavaScript and Intern, not Java, Maven and Jacoco.

Comment: You'll also need this other properties: sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
sonar.junit.reportsPath=build/test-results
sonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco
sonar.jacoco.reportPath=build/jacoco/test.exec I will edit the answer